# Strip unwanted characters from a string

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a string as input.
What is the best way to strip from the string the following unwanted characters?

```
!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:";'<>?,./`~\|)
```

Is there another way besides iterating over the string and matching character by character?

Comment: Step 1: Enclose those characters between square brackets `[]`. Step 2: escape the inner square closing bracket `\]`. Step 3: ? Step 4: Profit!

Comment: It far safer to specify which characters you want to keep.

Comment: You mentioned `”` and `’`, but what about `"` and `'`?

Comment: @ikegami:Arent' they the same characters?

Comment: You can't see the difference? You posted U+201D (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) and U+2019 (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK), I posted U+0022 (QUOTATION MARK) and a U+0027 (APOSTROPHE).

Comment: @ikegami:You are right. I was confused on this somehow (and copy/paste problem from my terminal). I actually wanted `"` and `'`. Thank you for noticing that

Answer (score 3):

“*It far safer to specify which characters you want to keep.*”

In this case, it appears that you've listed every punctuation character on a standard keyboard to be stripped.  The only thing that you didn't specify were letters, numbers and spaces.

Therefore use a negated character class that will filter out anything that doesn't match your desired characters to accomplish the same goal in a clearer and safer way:

```
s/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+//g;
```

Comment: I would second this approach, so long as you (the OP) wish to prevent Unicode characters, so German ß, Latin characters, etc. would be removed.

Comment: But perhaps use tr/// instead of s///. It'll probably be more efficient.

Comment: @DaveCross I feel that is likely a premature optimization, given that I specifically wanted to be able to use the `\s` character class, and perhaps the OP might want to use other character classes.  However, you are correct, and the following would be equivalent to my regex: `tr/a-zA-Z0-9 \t\n\r//cd;`

Answer (score 2):

```
$string =~ tr|!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:”;’<>?,./`~\\\|)||d;
```